# Kdb database to NumPy array in PyQ

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, kdb, pyq

I have a splayed Kdb database of symbols, floats, and timestamps. I'd like to convert this to NumPy arrays. However using the following code...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from pyq import q
>>> d = q.load(':alpha/HDB/')
>>> a = np.array(d)
```

Returns this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/marrowgari/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyq/_n.py", line 158, in array
return numpy.array(list(self), dtype)
TypeError: iteration over a K scalar, t=-11
```

Is this because Kdb symbol types do not have a direct analogue in NumPy? If so, how do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your HDB was created as follows:

```
q)(` sv db,`t`)set .Q.en[db:`:alpha/HDB]([]sym:`A`B`C;a:1 2 3)
`:alpha/HDB/t/
q)\l alpha/HDB
q)t
sym a
-----
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

Then, first of all you should load it using `\l` command, not the load function:

```
>>> q('\\l alpha/HDB')
k('::')
```

This will load all your tables and enumeration domains.

Now you should be able to convert the sym column of your table to a numpy array of strings

```
>>> np.array(q.t.sym)
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

or to a numpy array of integers:

```
>>> np.array(q.t.sym.data)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

You can also convert the entire table to a numpy record array in one go, but you will have to "map" it into the memory first:

```
>>> np.array(q.t.select())
array([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)], dtype=[('sym', 'O'), ('a', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Solved it. Thanks, Alexander. Curious to know, what is the reasoning behind loading using `\l` and not the load function?

Comment: `.q.load` is equivalent to KDB `load`, which is different to `\l` -
 see here: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#load

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `.q.load` does what you're expecting - the return of this function is simply a null symbol. I think instead you need to use `.q.get` e.g.

```
jmcmurray@host ~/hdb $ pyq
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> q.load("sym")
k('`sym')
>>> np.array(q.get(":2014.04.21/trades").select())
array([('AAPL', '2014-04-21T08:00:37.853000000', 'O',  25.33, 5048),
       ('AAPL', '2014-04-21T08:00:58.840000000', 'O',  25.35, 4580),
       ('AAPL', '2014-04-21T08:01:40.150000000', 'O',  25.35, 5432), ...,
       ('YHOO', '2014-04-21T16:29:06.868000000', 'L',  35.32, 4825),
       ('YHOO', '2014-04-21T16:29:43.655000000', 'L',  35.32, 6125),
       ('YHOO', '2014-04-21T16:29:57.229000000', 'L',  35.36,   41)],
      dtype=[('sym', 'O'), ('time', '<M8[ns]'), ('src', 'O'), ('price', '<f8'), ('size', '<i4')])
>>>
```

Note here I first use `.q.load` to load the `sym` file, as the symbol columns are enumerated. Then I load one splayed table from my HDB, which should be equivalent to your splayed table.

I also use `.select()` on the table as `.q.get()` simply maps the table into memory (same as `get` in KDB), it's necessary to use `select` to pull the actual data into memory.